# How to reference a class i guess?

Tags: c#

So simply put im trying to make a chat bot so I have chosen to make another class for my Stream writer so I've made a public class and then put a method etc. How would I mention that class in my main class in my main method?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        

    }

}
public class FileCreater2
{
    public void Main2(string[] args)
    {
        StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter("Test_File.text");
        File.Write("Hello world");
        File.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileCreater2 fc2 = new FileCreater2();
        fc2.Main2(null); //null passed just for demo
    }

    private class FileCreater2
    {
        public void Main2(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter("Test_File.text");
            File.Write("Hello world");
            File.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Quick question when we mention fc2.Main2 what are we doing there also  why a private class and not a public?

Comment: @Ausnix - you ca make it public if you want and shift it outside of the Program class as well.  You are 'instantiating' a new object of the type FileCreater2, then calling the Main2 method on that object.  Hit the tick if you think I've answered - cheers.